# Firebase Offline Database Data is Cleared when i restart Mobile Device or This android/firebase App ?*

Tags: synchronization, firebase-realtime-database

**i use this code for offline and synchronize the data in android app using firebase.
Firebase Offline Database Data is Cleared when i restart Mobile Device or This android/firebase App ?**

```
    DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
    scoresRef.keepSynced(true);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myConnectionsRef = database.getReference("users/joe/connections");
```

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
        final DatabaseReference lastOnlineRef = database.getReference("/users/joe/lastOnline");

```
    final DatabaseReference connectedRef = database.getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {



        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {

                // add this device to my connections list
                // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
                DatabaseReference con = myConnectionsRef.push();
                con.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

                // when this device disconnects, remove it
                con.onDisconnect().removeValue();

                // when I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
                lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled at .info/connected");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You might want to read about Firebase's disk persistence, which (on native mobile) persists the synchronized data to disk so that it'll survive application restarts: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-offline-behavior

Answer (score 0):

*********** write this code before mFirebaseDatabase.getReference()*********

```
     mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    // Fire up data persistence to work offline.
    // It's used once in app (not in each activity).
    try {
        mFirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        // Do anything
    }
```